# How to query the data that has been modified in last 24 hours

Tags: soql, rest-api

How to define the "where clause" in SFDC SOQL to extract the date that have been modified in last 24 hours. Thanks.

PS : I am using the QUERY rest URI for query the data.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the existing LastModifiedDate or SystemModStamp fields in your SOQL query (See [System Fields](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/system_fields.htm)). The `LAST_N_DAYS` or `TODAY` date [literals](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) may be useful. Otherwise you can use a specific calculated UTC Date time value.

```
Select Id from Account where SystemModStamp >= LAST_N_DAYS:1
Select Id from Account where SystemModStamp >= 2014-11-19T23:01:01Z
```

There was a recent blog post on the performance implications of LastModifiedDate vs SystemModStamp - [Force.com SOQL Performance Tips: LastModifiedDate vs SystemModStamp](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/11/force-com-soql-performance-tips-systemmodstamp-vs-lastmodifieddate-2.html?d=70130000000llMA)

Comment: Thanks it's working fine.. what's the difference between systemModStamp and lastmodifiedDate.

Comment: @AnkitKhandelwal The differences are covered in the linked [System Fields](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/system_fields.htm) and [Performance Tips](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/11/force-com-soql-performance-tips-systemmodstamp-vs-lastmodifieddate-2.html?d=70130000000llMA) pages. `SystemModstamp` gets updated for **all** changes and is strictly read-only. `LastModifiedDate` is only for user changes and can be updated.

Comment: Below query won't give last 24 hours data , if I don't run it  @ 12 in Midnight.. I have a java program that schedule @ 8 pm ever ngiht and I have get the data for last 24 hours.                                  /services/data/v32.0/query/?q=select ID from Custom_Object_HDS__c where LastModifiedDate = Today

Comment: @AnkitKhandelwal look at the definitions of the Date Time [literals](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm). They are defined along the lines of "Starts 12:00:00 of the current day and continues for 24 hours". You will need to manually calculate the required UTC date literal as per the second example query.